# Html form to email

Tags: php, html

I have a contact form that i try to send to an email. For that reason i created a html form and a PHP Script in XAMPP under the htdocs file. My Project is in an another file in htdocs. Problem: when i submit the form i recieve something like this: No data recieve" from Browser. what is the problem. Is there something wrong with the Script? please Help..

```html
<form method="post" action="formprocess.php" >
<div class=" form-group">
<div class="row-lg-2">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row-lg-2">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1">Your Name</label>
<input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row-lg-2">
<label for="yourmessage">Your Message here</label>
<textarea class="form-control" name="mmessage" id="yourmessage" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit your message</button>
</div>
</div> 
</form>
```

```html
 PHP Script

<?php
$TO = "elmail@provider.com";

$h = "From: " . $TO;

$message = "";

while (list($key, $val) = each($HTTP_POST_VARS)) {
$message .= "$key : $val\n";
}

mail($TO, $subject, $message, $h);
Header("Location: http://localhost:8383/folder/index.html"); 


?>
```

Thk you

Answer (score 0):

You can try using PHPMailer , it is easy to configure and use SMTP. Probably the world's most popular code for sending email from PHP.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer